# Comparar dois arrays de numeros

Tags: php, array

Estou com dificuldade de fazer uma comparação no `PHP` entre dois `arrays`.

Tenho o Array `HORA_INICIAL` e `HORA_FINAL`
o que estou precisando fazer :

No array Hora Inicial comparar o `Hora Inicial < Hora Final` e exibir o indice do Hora Final ser maior.

Comment: apresenta esses arrays e um exemplo do resultado desejado

Comment: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-diff.php

Comment: Hora_INI | Hora_Fim<br>
0110000 | 0080000<br>
1130000 | 1140000<br>

Como podem ver na linha 1 tem um valor que eh maior na Hora Inicial, preciso saber como verificar linha a linha e exibir uma mensagem de erro.
No caso a linha 1 tem um erro, pois a hora Inicial eh maior que a Hora_Final

Comment: Isso não é um `array`, você está lendo essa linha e convertendo?

Comment: Aqui eu formatei.
Eu tenho as duas variaveis que estao com os valores array.
$dtINI ; $dtFIM nelas tao armazenada os valores.

Comment: Pode colocar o Hora Inicial e Hora Final por favor como exemplo de dados na sua pergunta?

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi bem você tem **dois arrays** com a mesma quantidade de elementos, que devem ser comparados com base no seu índice, para saber se o primeiro tem valor maior que o segundo.

Vamos exemplificar:

```
// Array com as horas iniciais
$arrayHoraInicial = array(
    '09:32:00',
    '11:20:10',
    '13:06:55',
    '19:10:10',
);

// Array com as horas finais
$arrayHoraFinal = array(
    '09:50:00',
    '12:10:00',
    '12:25:15',
    '21:11:08',
);

// Captura quantos elementos existem no array.    
$quantidade = count($arrayHoraInicial); 

// Realiza um loop for para percorrer os arrays.    
for ($i = 0; $i < $quantidade; $i++) {
    // Compara horas string
    if($arrayHoraFinal[$i] < $arrayHoraInicial[$i]) {
        echo "O índice $i apresenta um valor final maior que o inicial";
    }
}
```

No exemplo acima o resultado impresso será:

O índice 2 apresenta um valor final maior que o inicial